# How can I disable KafkaAdmin when using spring boot

Tags: spring-kafka

Currently I'm using Spring boot 2.4.0 with spring-kafka.

I want to use consumers and producers but not kafka admin.

I tried to override `KafkaAdmin` class by settings "bootstrap.servers" to null, but doesn't work. It still
'try' to connect to make KafkaAdmin and log errors. It's not fatal, but is there any way to totally disable kafka admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your concern does not make sense. The `KafkaAdmin` does not connect by itself. The logic there is like this:

```
public final boolean initialize() {
        Collection<NewTopic> newTopics = this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(NewTopic.class, false, false).values();
        if (newTopics.size() > 0) {
            AdminClient adminClient = null;
            try {
                Map<String, Object> configs2 = new HashMap<>(this.configs);
                checkBootstrap(configs2);
                adminClient = AdminClient.create(configs2);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (!this.initializingContext || this.fatalIfBrokerNotAvailable) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create admin", e);
                }
                else {
                    LOGGER.error(e, "Could not create admin");
                }
            }
```

So, if there is no any `NewTopic` beans in the application context the `KafkaAdmin` does nothing. If you have some, then what is the reason for that, if not create new topics on the broker before producing/consuming. Therefore `KafkaAdmin` logic.

Comment: You're right. I found that there are some `NewTopic` Beans. Thank you!